# How to excute one hyperledger composer transaction in two hours timeInterval

Tags: hyperledger-composer

async function autoGrantStarCoin(){

```
setInterval(function() {
    process.nextTick(function(){
        grantStarCoin()
    })
}, 10000);
```

}

this way is wrong

Comment: Set up a cron job, or a task in suitable job scheduler, to run the transaction client side using something like `composer transaction submit` - see https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/composer.transaction.submit.html with the appropriate business network card provided to the `-c` flag.

Comment: As well as composer transaction submit CLI, you can drive it via a REST API using something like curl, or even programatically client-side using the Node.js APIs within something like OpenWhisk or AWS Lambda.

Comment: Thank you for your answers , I want one participant transfer some commodity to another one every two hours inner chaincode.

Comment: async function autoGrantStarCoin(){
   setInterval(await grantStarCoin(),72000);
}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are asking a question or stating the answer, however to confirm you should not set up any sort of automated timer inside node.js chaincode or a composer business network. This will not work and is not a good idea in general anyway (even if you do find a way to make it work)
You need to set a timer up client side and make the request.

Comment: async function autoGrantStarCoin(){

   setInterval(await grantStarCoin(),72000);
  
}